# `sorting=none` results in wrong order for ten or more references in one \cite{}

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

I want to create a bibliography with BibLaTeX, and since I want the references to appear in citation order, I use the package option `sorting=none`.  However, at one point in my document, I need to cite ten references at once, i.e. with one `\cite{}` command.  In this case the (none-)sorting in the bibliography goes wrong.

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@article{test:a, title = {Test a}}
@article{test:b, title = {Test b}}
@article{test:c, title = {Test c}}
@article{test:d, title = {Test d}}
@article{test:e, title = {Test e}}
@article{test:f, title = {Test f}}
@article{test:g, title = {Test g}}
@article{test:h, title = {Test h}}
@article{test:i, title = {Test i}}
@article{test:j, title = {Test j}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Tests are great \cite{test:a,test:b,test:c,test:d,test:e,test:f,test:g,test:h,test:i,test:j}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compiling this (with `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`) results in a bibliography in which the references appear in the wrong order: the 10th entry `test:j` appears second, between `test:a` and `test:b`; see the following screenshot.

[image: Compilation result, with wrong bibliography order]

To me, it seems that at some point in the process of creating the bibliography, the references are sorted by their position in the `\cite{}` command *not numerically, but lexicographically*, resulting in reference no. 10 appearing between no. 1 and no. 2.

Interestingly, this seems to be some kind of Biber problem: using BibLaTeX with `backend=bibtex` and compiling with `bibtex` instead of `biber` sorts the bibliography correctly.

Did I overlook something, or have I found a bug in Biber?

(I’m on TeX Live 2022, with Biber version 2.18 and BibLaTeX  version 3.18b.)

Comment: I get 1 to 10 with texlive 2023: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YJt4.png (biblatex v3.19; biber 2.19)

Comment: I might have found the problem. In biber 2.18, the `intciteorder` sort field was introduced (order of entries in one `\cite{}`), and has since been used for `sorting=none`.  However, apparently `intciteorder` was treated as a string rather than an integer, leading to precisely the mis-sorting I encountered.  This got corrected in https://github.com/plk/biber/commit/7942d2e1c93adec9abb2723a043cc2538d84fcbc, which got incorporated in biber 2.19.

Comment: Please write an self answer, that is welcome here!

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a bug in Biber v2.18 that got resolved in v2.19.

Biber 2.18 introduced the `intciteorder` sort field (the order of entries in one `\cite{}`), which has since been used for `sorting=none`.  However, for sorting `intciteorder` was erroneously treated as a string rather than an integer, leading to precisely the wrong sorting behaviour described in the question. This got corrected in [commit `7942d2e` of Biber](https://github.com/plk/biber/commit/7942d2e1c93adec9abb2723a043cc2538d84fcbc), which got incorporated in Biber v2.19.

(So I either need to update to TeX Live 2023 [while being on Debian stable] or find some other workaround …)

Comment: You could ditch the linux texlive package and install texlive directly from https://tug.org/texlive/ This way, you can always update when you wish.